# HTML5 nav - How to change default caption "Navigation" on mobile browsers?

Tags: html, mobile, browser, nav, caption

I use a nav -tag on my website and as I browse it on mobile browser it has a default caption "Navigation". How can I change this to something else?

Comment: Hit right click on your nav-tag then select inspect element. Get it's class/id and then change it Javascript/j query. Also you should post some source code if you want more help.

Comment: Thanks, got it! Just needed general guidance on how to do it, didn't know it can be changed through javascript :).